# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 32, 32]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
import imageio
import glob
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trainImages = []
for imagePath in glob.glob('C:/Users/razva/*.png'):
     image = imageio.imread(imagePath)
     trainImages.append(image)
trainImages = np.array(trainImages)

f = open('C:/Users/razva/train.txt')
trainLabels = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(trainLabels)):
     trainLabels[i] = int(trainLabels[i][11])
trainLabels = np.array(trainLabels)

validationImages = []
for imagePath in glob.glob('C:/Users/razva/*.png'):
     image = imageio.imread(imagePath)
     validationImages.append(image)
validationImages = np.array(validationImages)
f = open('C:/Users/razva/validation.txt')
validationLabels = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(validationLabels)):
     validationLabels[i] = int(validationLabels[i][11])
validationLabels = np.array(validationLabels)

mean_image = np.mean(trainImages, axis = 0)
sd = np.std(trainImages)
trainImages = (trainImages - mean_image) / sd

mean_image1 = np.mean(validationImages, axis = 0)
sd1 = np.std(validationImages)
validationImages = (validationImages - mean_image1) / sd1

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainImages, trainLabels, epochs=10, validation_data=(validationImages, validationLabels))
```

I have this cnn for image classification, trainImages and trainLabel(from 0 to 8) are training data, validationImages and validationLabels are for test. Images are 32 * 32. I cant make this algorithm work, tell me if u observe more errors pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly where the problem is since I have no access to the loaded images, but the issue is that you are providing samples without the "channel" axis which in the specified `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)` is indicated as having size 3. Each sample (image) must have 3 dimensions (width, height, channels) but, on the contrary, you are passing samples with just 2 dimensions (width and height).

This is most likely due to the fact that you are probably loading gray-scale images with just one channel, which is not explicitly assigned an axis by numpy. If this is the case, make sure that both *trainImages* and *validationImages* have shape (32, 32, 1), otherwise just expand the last dimension with `np.expand_dims(_trainImages_, axis=-1)` (same for the validation set) before feeding them to the model. Accordingly, adjust to (32, 32, 1) the input_shape in the first Conv2D layer.

Hope it helps, otherwise let me have further details.

Comment: @Babenco5 Just call `model.predict(.)` on a batch of images you want to classify. Then, since you are outputting logits, you need to apply `np.argmax(prediction_result, axis=-1)` to obtain a batch of predicted labels corresponding to the given inputs. With regard to this, since you have 9 labels (from 0 to 8, as you said), I believe you should have 9 neurons in the last Dense layer (not 10, as you do).

P.S. If my answer was helpful, please accept it.